# Simple way to get NFC tag uid

Tags: c#, usb, nfc

Is there a simple way to get the uid of a NFC tag/ smartcard/ token in C#? Got the ACR1252u NFC reader/writer which supports ISO 14443 Typ A and B. The tags I want to read are from Mifare (DESFire, Ultralight) and Topaz 512.

Got already a solution from this example: http://the--semicolon.blogspot.de/p/this-is-simple-way-to-restart-your.html

That works but isn´t there an more simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no really simple way. But since your reader/writer seems to be PC/SC compliant, you are in luck.

Microsoft has a PC/SC implementation named WinScard. You will need this dll to send and receive APDUs from the card.

However, it is hardly usable on its own. You need to write wrappers for its classes or use an existing library. Personally, I use PC/SC sharp (https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp). It includes many examples on different use cases.

Comment: Okay, thats exactly what I use at the moment. Do you know if every NFC reader/writer which is PC/SC compliant is supported by the winscard.dll?

Comment: Yes. WinScard implements PC/SC, so by definition, every PC/SC reader/writer should be supported. There are, however, reader/writers which are not PC/SC compliant, but I couldn't tell you the ratio.

Comment: @ Christophe Maybe you can also help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311358/method-replys-unplugged-nfc-readers

Comment: I am using the same method you posted in your own answer. If there is a better way, I am not aware of it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for looking at it.